# MYSQL : WHERE (2 Conditions) is not working

Tags: mysql

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM quete WHERE zone_quete = 1, id_quete NOT IN (select id_queteorij
             FROM quetejoueur
             WHERE id_joueur = :id) ');      
$query->bindValue(':id', $donnees["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

So, here's my code. I don't really know why this is not working.

- `SELECT * FROM quete` : I want it to select everything from my database "`quete`"
- `WHERE zone_quete = 1` : I want the code to only SELECT the rows where `zone_quete` = 1
- The rest : I want the code to only SELECT the rows where id_quete is not the same as the "id_queteorij" in quetejoueur where id_joueur = :id (:id is the ID of the player)

It only works if I put 1 of them, I can't put both of them and that's a problem.

Thanks for the help !

**EDIT : OOPS, it was not "," but "AND" to separate the conditions. My bad !**

Comment: Not `,`, use `AND` or `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use AND  id_quete NOT IN

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
          FROM quete 
          WHERE zone_quete = 1 AND  id_quete NOT IN (
              SELECT id_queteorij
              FROM quetejoueur
              WHERE id_joueur = :id) ');     

$query->bindValue(':id', $donnees["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```